# Given an equation with x, y, z and a constant, how do I find the center and radius of a sphere?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, spheres

So for my vector calculus homework I was given:

$$
(x^2+4x)+(y^2-6y)+(z^2+10z)=11
$$

and told to find the center and radius of the sphere this describes. Where do I even start? I know in general a sphere can be described as:
$$
(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2+(z-l)^2=r^2
$$
but obviously this doesn't as easily map onto that, so how do I figure this out?
Thanks!

Comment: Complete the square on each variable to obtain the desired form.

Answer (score 2):

Begin with $$(x^2+4x)+(y^2-6y)+(z^2+10z)=11$$

Complete the square within each bracket:

$$(x^2+4x+4)+(y^2-6y+9)+(z^2+10z+25)=11+4+9+25$$

Factor:

$$(x+2)^2+(y-3)^2+(z+5)^2=7^2$$

The center of this sphere is $(-2, 3, -5)$ and the radius is $7$.